# restrict children count till 6th level in a tree

Tags: php, mysql

the php function i made gets all the children of a the parent in tree form . The problem is that it gets all the children but i want to restrict it till level 6th of the tree . The code i made is

```
get_childs("2");

function get_childs($parent_id){
GLOBAL $con;
     if ($result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE referred_by='$parent_id'")) {
         echo '<ul>';

         while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row['user_id'].'</a>';

             //call again for each child. if the id dosen't have childs, then prints nothing and go on!
             get_childs($row['user_id']);

             echo '</li>';
        }// end while

        echo '</ul>';
     }// end if select

}
```

The output it generates

[image]

I want to restrict it till 17 as in above output as the level 6th reaches there .

Comment: Pass a 'count' parameter', which prevents `get_childs` from getting called at Level 'x'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, I'd suggest something like this:

```
get_childs("2", 0);

function get_childs($parent_id, $level){
    GLOBAL $con;
    if ($result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE referred_by='$parent_id'")) {
         echo '<ul>';

         while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row['user_id'].'</a>';

             //call again for each child. if the id dosen't have childs, then prints nothing and go on!
            if($level < 6)
                get_childs($row['user_id'], $level + 1);

            echo '</li>';
        }// end while

        echo '</ul>';
    }// end if select
}
```

With this tiny alteration, your tree will stop as soon as the 6th level is reached. (You might have to tweak it a tiny bit)

Comment: Thnak you @ATaylor this helped a lot .

Answer (score 2):

```
get_childs("2", 6);

function get_childs($parent_id, $level){
    if($level < 1) return false;
GLOBAL $con;
     if ($result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE referred_by='$parent_id'")) {
         echo '<ul>';

         while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row['user_id'].'</a>';

             //call again for each child. if the id dosen't have childs, then prints nothing and go on!
             get_childs($row['user_id'], $level--);

             echo '</li>';
        }// end while

        echo '</ul>';
     }// end if select

}
```

Comment: Ah, I see you chose the inverse approach, where you can choose which level to stop at. Yeah, that should work too.

Comment: Sorry but this didnt worked . But Thank you so much @Sanith to help me